# Counting in sequences

Tags: function

Say I want to count values in sequence xs of how many times it appears in v and return the integers in a list in the same order. Including dups. This the code I have so far and I'm kind of stuck on what to do. Trying to keep it simple **without** .count funcs and what not.

```
def count_each(xs,v):
count = []
for i in range(len(xs)):
    if xs(i) == v:
        return count.append(i)
    return count
```

Comment: What is the desired output for this? Also fix the indentation

Comment: Please post an input/ouput example.

Comment: count_each([10,20,30],[10,20,50,20,40,20]) → [1,3,0] <- This is what I wanted.

Comment: How could an int ever be equal to a list?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep it simple"? Why and to what are you limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample function to achieve this using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_each(xs, v):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for item in v:
        if item in xs:
           count[item] += 1
    return [count[item] for item in xs]
```

OR, using simple `dict` as:

```
def count_each(xs, v):
    count = {}
    for item in v:
        if item in xs:
           if item not in count:
               count[item] = 0
           count[item] += 1
    return [count.get(item, 0) for item in xs]
```

Sample call:

```
>>> count_each([10,20,30],[10,20,50,20,40,20])
[1, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Is there another method other than defaultdict? Would like to try it with just lists, sequences,loops without built in functions.

Comment: Is it what your desired?

Comment: you should be using a collections.Counter instead of a vanilla dictionary. This greatly simplifies the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the list method [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
>>> keys = [10, 20, 30]
>>> search = [10, 20, 50, 20, 40, 20]
>>> print [search.count(key) for key in keys]
[1, 3, 0]
```

alternatively *O(n)*,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(search)
>>> print [c[key] for key in keys]
[1, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Counter is the correct solution here, as it makes only one pass through the search space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `list.count(element)` to count `element` in `list`

So your code can look like this

```
def count_each(xs, v):

    result = []

    for element in xs:
        result.append( v.count(element) )

    return result

count_each([10,20,30],[10,20,50,20,40,20])
```

or you can write it shorter using `list comprehension` - see @mrdomoboto answer.

---

**EDIT:** the same **without** count()

```
def count_each(xs, v):

    result = []

    for element in xs:

        count = 0

        for x in v:
            if x == element:
                count += 1

        result.append( count )

    return result

count_each([10,20,30],[10,20,50,20,40,20])
```

**BTW:** you can't do this with `dict` because `dict` don't have to keep order. One time you can get result `[1,3,0]` but another time `[3,1,0]` or `[0,1,3]`, etc.

Comment: You can certainly do this problem using a dictionary. Lets say our unsorted `dict` -> `d = {10:1, 30:0, 20:3}`. When we've counted all of our integers, we can assemble our final list using -> `[d[key] for key in [10, 20, 30]]`.

Comment: @mrdomoboto No you can't - read python doc - dict don't have to keep order. Mostly it keeps it but sometimes you can get results in different order. And this is why we have `collections.OrderedDict()`

Comment: Of course dictionaries don't ensure insertion order, that's why I explicitly list a list comprehension to collect the results in order using the original search key list. My point being you can certainly use a dictionary to collect the count data.

Comment: oh, now I see. Yes now it can keep order.